# cakePHP 3 Query ifnull

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, resultset, query-builder, ifnull

I wonder what would be the best way to prevent null results in a ResultSet. I'm on cake 3.5.13 and I'm using cases, like:

```
private function addCase($isforeign, $source)
{
    $query = $this->Sales->find();
    return $query->newExpr()
        ->addCase(
            $query->newExpr()->add([
                'Sales.isforeign' => $isforeign,
                'Sales.source' => $source
            ]),
            1,
            'integer');
}
```

I then put the return of my addCase function in

```
(..)
'sourcenationalcount' => $query->func()->sum($this->addCase(0, 1)),
(..)
```

Now it is possible that sourcenationalcount could become null. What would be the best way to return the value 0 instead. I wasn't able to find a `func()->ifnull()`. Should I use a `formatResult()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions builder can create any function you want, you just need to call it, and the magic method call handler of the builder will create a generic function call in case there is no concrete method implemented, ie `func()->ifnull()` will just work.

However, `IFNULL` is MySQL/SQLite specific, so in order to keep things as portable as possible, I'd suggest to simply use an `ELSE` case instead, one that selects `0` instead of `NULL` in case the conditions evaluate to `FALSE`.

```
$query
    ->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
        [
            $query->newExpr()->add([
                'Sales.isforeign' => $isforeign,
                'Sales.source' => $source
            ])
        ],
        [1, 0],
        ['integer', 'integer']
    );
```

That should generate SQL similar to:

```sql
CASE WHEN (Sales.isforeign = 0 AND Sales.source = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions > Case Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**

Comment: When I extend the addCase like you suggested, I recieve the following SQL: `(SUM(CASE WHEN (Sales.isforeign = :c11 AND Sales.source = :c12) THEN :param13 END)) AS sourcenationalcount `. I won't get the ELSE part.

Comment: @Seb You might not have changed it correctly, I can't tell from here. The example snippet works as expected, and you should be able to just copy & paste it.

Comment: Dumb me! I missed the array around `$query->newExpr()..`. Thanks alot ndm! :)