# replace null or empty response from other static word in cakephp 3 query

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp 3 to replace with a static word in place of null/empty column value.

**For Example :-** 
I have a product table which contain id,price,image, I need to fetch all the records but which product's does not have image, it should return "no_image.jpg" in place of null/empty.

Like : 
SELECT if(image='','no_image.jpg', image), id, price FROM user_images.
how can i convert above query in cakephp 3.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129058/cakephp-3-query-ifnull

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do this in the query and would show no_image.jpg for null image values while outputting the records instead. You may have a good reason for doing it in the database, but just another option to consider.

Comment: Thanks, above link solved my problem. :)

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NULLIF` to set NULL when image = ''.

Then use `COALESCE` to return the second parameter if first is null.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(image,''), 'no_image.jpg') as image, id, price FROM user_images
```

In other words, if image is NULL or '', it will return `no_image.jpg`,, else it will return the image itself.

- NULLIF: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_nullif.asp
- COALESCE: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp

Of course, you  can also return null/empty and put this logic in application, not in the query.